# connect arduino to arduino mega adk by USB

Tags: arduino, wifi

I have an arduino mega ADK, with usb port, and an arduino uno.
- On the arduino uno, I put a xBee shield with the wifly module for connect to the internet.
- On the arduino mega ADK, I put the TinkerKit! shield.

I need to use both : xBee shield and TinkerKit!. and the single way i found, is to connect the arduino uno to the arduino mega ADK by USB wire (the wire is the one I use to connect an arduino to my computer).

Do you think it could work ? If yes, How can I get what is writting on the outpu of the arduino uno ? If no, is there an other way to do what I need ?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it can be done, but is is way more easier to use directly the Hardware/Software Serial. Even if you get iw work, it will be a serial simulation over usb..
So using USB is just a layer of complexity that can break, and nothing more.